# Getting InvalidCredential and Permission error while using geocoder and here api

Tags: angular, here-api, geocoder

I'm passing state name and want to get the lat and long of the state. But i'm unable to get the response while hitting. Using the app_id and app_code getting from here developers console. Error i'm getting

**H.service.jsonp.handleResponse(2)(invalid credentials for rPR8jXBgboz6xZYrrg53)**

Comment: H.service.jsonp.handleResponse(2)(<ns2:Error xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Errors/1" type="PermissionError" subtype="InvalidCredentials"><Details>invalid credentials for app-code</Details></ns2:Error>)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which API you are using but you can check the new HERE domains as new recommendation is to use the apikey instead of app_id/app_code for security purpose.

Link for the changed domain names-
https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/topics/hosts-mapping.html

Also example request for you to check

```
https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=Rajasthan&apiKey={}
```